# No route matches [DELETE] "/users/sign_out" on Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, session, routes, devise

I just found out about this issue today as I'm reviewing all my projects and all the other posts I found either seem to be about earlier versions of Rails or have solutions I looked into.

I'm trying to sign out my users and I get this error `No route matches [DELETE] "/users/sign_out"`.

Here's my link,

```
<%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, :class => 'navbar-link'  %>
```

My Routes, I'm also using omniauth to sign in with third parties.

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "callbacks" }
```

And here's what I have in `devise.rb`

```
config.sign_out_via = :get
```

The browser's console log gives me this error:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/users/sign_out 404 (Not Found)
```

And the Rails log show me this:

```
Started DELETE "/users/sign_out" for ::1 at 2022-03-06 11:07:46 -0600
  
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [DELETE] "/users/sign_out"):
```

Is there anything I still need to check? Please advise.

Comment: Its almost guarenteed to be a issue with Rails UJS. And if you want to guarentee that it works without JS just use `<%= button_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, :class => 'navbar-link'  %>`. This creates an actual form that sends a POST request with a `_method="DELETE"` parameter. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v6.1/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#data-method
`

Comment: This is one of the most repeated Rails questions on Stackoverflow and it can't quite be closed as a duplicate since their are so many potential causes (rails ujs is missing from the assets manifest, broken js, clashes with other libraries etc) and the questions itself never contains any actual useful debugging information (rails logs, browser console etc) so don't take it personally if this question gets closed/downvoted.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I checked the console. I get ```POST http://localhost:3000/users/sign_out 404 (Not Found)```. The Rails log only gives me the following. ```Started DELETE "/users/sign_out" for ::1 at 2022-03-06 11:03:57 -0600
  
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [DELETE] "/users/sign_out"):``` I'll edit the question with this information but it's the only thing I got so far.

Comment: Ah. Now I see the problem. `config.sign_out_via = :get` will ONLY generate a GET route. If you want to allow both GET and DELETE use `config.sign_out_via = [:get, :delete]` but you shouldn't really even need to monkey with this in the first place as `config.sign_out_via = :get` is the "Waah, too hard" cop out when Rails UJS is broken.

Comment: Yeah, it's weird cause I've seen using ```config.sign_out_via = :get``` as a suggestion and answer in all this bunch of similar questions. That's probably why I've had it like that in the first place. Adding DELETE solved the issue, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing `config.sign_out_via = :get` to `config.sign_out_via = [:get, :delete]` solved the issue.

Please refer to the comments (thanks again, max). My suggestion is checking Rails UJS before doing the `config.sign_out_via = :get`, while it might be a solution. It will come back to bite you (like it just did with me). Perhaps, checking if there's a new Rails UJS version or if it's missing from the assets manifest might be better.